# Launch shell scripts from anywhere

Tags: command-line, scripts, paths

Is it possible to run my scripts located in `~/scripts` from anywhere?

Say i want to run `./scriptname` regardless of my current working directory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add `~/scripts` to your `$PATH` environment variable. Then you can run `scriptname` from anywhere (but not `./scriptname`, because the `./` denotes the current directory).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) shows how to add `~/bin` to `$PATH`, but you can do the same with `~/scripts` of course.

Answer (score 18):

Add

```
 export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts
```

to your the end of your `~/.bashrc` file. This will allow you to execute your scripts in `~/scripts/` by simply typing scriptname in the bash.
You need to logout in order for it to work in your session (you can test the scripts by opening a new terminal).

I usually add

```
 export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

to my path and then create symlinks to the scripts an programs I want to have available in my session.

```
cd ~/bin
ln -s ~/Tools/eclipse3.7/eclipse 
# which will create a symlink in ~/bin/ with the name eclipse
# pointing to ~/Tools/eclipse3.7/eclipse which allows me to execute
# the eclipse in ~/Tools/eclipse3.7/
```

Note that the path files have a precedence. If I already have installed eclipse through ubuntu, it will first search eclipse in all other places than in `~/bin/`. If you want to change this behavior just export the directory the other way around:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Make sure the scripts in your scripts directory are executable otherwise the export won't have an effect.

You can look at the available paths by typing

```
echo $PATH
```

If you want to see all environment variables type `env` in your console.

Comment: +1 Well put answer. I usually add my bin at the *front* of the `PATH`. This way I can use my „own version” of commands. And as a side note, you don't need the trailing slash after the directory name.

Comment: Thanks! You are right I removed the slashes in my comment. I wanted to provide a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

- call your shell scripts with a full path instead of `./`, like `~/scripts/scriptname`
- add the folder that contains your shell scripts to the `$PATH` environment variable and call your shell scripts without the leading `./`, like `scriptname`

Comment: Is this correct string, to add to PATH?  /my/path/myscript.sh